# Sharepoint Access Request "Permission" Codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am accessing the Access%20Requests/pendingreq.aspx list of a Sharepoint site in C#.

When trying to access what in the pendingreq.aspx page is written in the Permission column, I only get numbers like "0" (for a request trying to get Read permissions) or any other numerical code. I could not find a reference for these permission codes.

Is there a way to look up those codes in order to find a written description of the requested permission or do I have to discover and map these codes myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2011/10/23/list-of-sharepoint-base-permissions-with-their-hex-and-decimal-values/

The article has the entire list of permission names along with their Hex and decimal values.

Comment: Is this information still valid? And is there a way to retrieve those infos programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the list using SharePoint REST API and a REST client like Postman:

```
http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')

or

http://site url/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID')
```

Maybe you'll get more info about Permission column.